# .NET Entity Framework custom user table and column error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use my own tables for storing the users of my .NET 4.8.1 Entity Framework app. I have this application user model:

```cs
namespace GesTalento.Models
{
    // https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 para obtener más información.
    [Table("Usuario")]
    public class Usuario : IdentityUser
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string IdUsuario { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string TipoDeUsuario { get; set; }

        public int? IdCandidato { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Correo { get; set; }

        public bool CorreoConfirmado { get; set; }

        public string Contrasena { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<Usuario> manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que authenticationType debe coincidir con el valor definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar reclamaciones de usuario personalizadas aquí
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
}
```

Which corresponds to this database table:
[image: Database table screenshot]

And this database context:

```cs
namespace GesTalento.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
    {
        public DbSet<Entrevista> Entrevista { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Oferta> Oferta { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Candidato> Candidato { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Contacto> Contacto { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Familia> Familia { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Comentario> Comentario { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Habilidad> Habilidad { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Requisito> Requisito { get; set; }

        // public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("name=GestionTalento")
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
                .ToTable("Usuario")
                // .HasKey(p => p.IdUsuario)
                .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                .Ignore(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled)
                .Ignore(p => p.LockoutEnabled)
                .Ignore(p => p.LockoutEndDateUtc)
                .Ignore(p => p.AccessFailedCount)
                .Ignore(p => p.EmailConfirmed)
                .Ignore(p => p.PasswordHash)
                .Ignore(p => p.SecurityStamp)
                .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumber);
            // .Ignore(p => p.Claims)
            // .Ignore(p => p.Logins)
            //.Ignore(p => p.Roles)

            modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("IdUsuario");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("Correo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("Nombre");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to log in, the following line

```
var usuario = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Correo);
```

Causes this error

```
El nombre de columna 'IdUsuario1' no es válido.
El nombre de columna 'Nombre1' no es válido.
El nombre de columna 'Correo1' no es válido.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: El nombre de columna 'IdUsuario1' no es válido.
El nombre de columna 'Nombre1' no es válido.
El nombre de columna 'Correo1' no es válido.
```

Which says that the column name is invalid. Why does Entity Framework look for IdUsuario1, Correo1 and Nombre1? Why it adds a 1 to the column name?

Comment: Did you add a migration and update the database?

Comment: @Eldar No, I'm not using migrations, I manage the DB manually. I have added the DB table screenshot.

Comment: Your context says that you are using the code-first approach. If you don't want to use code first then you should scaffold DbContext from the database. [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: @Eldar what do you mean? I use `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext` as DbContext. I previously had another class which inherited DbContext but I can have everything in one class, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think, It causes mapping "Usuario" class twice by inheriting your "ApplicationDbContext" from "IdentityDbContext" which is also defines entity mapping for **Usuario** as IdentityUser. Then you don't need to map the **Usuario** class OnModelCreating anymore, if you marked it as identity user.

Answer (score 0):

You've commented out

```
// public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
```

Try uncommenting may be?

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing with Entity Framework looking for columns like 'IdUsuario1', 'Correo1', and 'Nombre1' is likely related to the fact that you are using the .Ignore method to exclude certain properties of the IdentityUser base class, but Entity Framework is still trying to create columns for them.

To resolve this issue, you can use the .Property method to configure the properties in a more detailed manner, making Entity Framework aware that you have handled them. Here's how you can update your OnModelCreating method:

```html
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
        .ToTable("Usuario")
        .Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("IdUsuario");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
        .Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("Correo");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
        .Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("Nombre");

    // Additional configuration for the properties you want to ignore
    modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
        .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        .Ignore(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled)
        .Ignore(p => p.LockoutEnabled)
        .Ignore(p => p.LockoutEndDateUtc)
        .Ignore(p => p.AccessFailedCount)
        .Ignore(p => p.EmailConfirmed)
        .Ignore(p => p.PasswordHash)
        .Ignore(p => p.SecurityStamp)
        .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I still get the same error :(